# (d3.js)(.csv) Exclude column from Stacked Bar Graph

Tags: csv, d3.js

I am using a single .csv file to generate two separate graphs.  One is a simple table and the other is a stacked bar graph.  The data is currently being read directly from the file as opposed to being converted to a string.

The data is a list of values where the last column is a sum of the values in each row. Ex:

```
Value1,Value2,Value3,Value4,Total
2,2,2,4,10
1,3,2,1,7
5,2,1,1,9
```

I would like the "Total" column to appear in my table, but not in my stacked bar graph, but would like to continue using a single data source.  Is there any way to exclude a specific column of data from my stacked bar graph?

I am using a copy/paste version of http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208

Comment: Based on the example you linked to, then `color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "State" && key !== "65 Years and Over"; }));`?

Comment: Works perfectly.  Thank you sir.  I was thrown off by the color.domain and was assuming that that was just setting the color for each value.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example you linked to, then

```
color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]
     .filter(function(key) { 
           return key !== "State" && key !== "65 Years and Over";
}));
```

Comment: And I was going to comment above, but will do it here, that the key line to understand is: `d.ages = color.domain().map(function(name) { return {name: name, y0: y0, y1: y0 += +d[name]}; });`, since `data(d).ages` is now based on our filtered columns and is the data used to display the rects.