# How to omit a column from stack?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a csv like:

```
name,x1,x2,x3,total
John,1,1,0,2
July,0,1,1,2
...
```

With this code all of the data is stacked:

```
var stackedData = d3.stack().keys(data.columns.slice(1))(data);
```

### Question

How do I construct `stackedData` such that I only have `x1`, `x2` and `x3`? In other words I'm omitting the `total` column from my stacked data.

Comment: Why not just use `Array.map` to map the structure you're after?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not mutate your original data array, you may need those values somewhere else. Also, you don't need to create a new data array, which can be an expensive process if the data is huge.

You can simply specify the keys you want to use with the stack generator. For instance:

```
const columns = data.columns.filter(function(d) {
  return d !== "name" && d !== "total";
});
```

And then:

```
const stackedData = d3.stack().keys(columns)(data);
//your keys here ----------------------^
```

Here is the demo:

```js
const csv = `name,x1,x2,x3,total
John,1,1,0,2
July,0,1,1,2
Foo,2,3,1,5
Bar,1,2,0,2
Baz,8,7,1,2`;

const data = d3.csvParse(csv, d3.autoType);

const columns = data.columns.filter(function(d) {
  return d !== "name" && d !== "total";
});

const stackedData = d3.stack().keys(columns)(data);

console.log(stackedData)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any out of the box way to do this with `stack`. One option is to use `Array.map` to create your new array of data without the column you want to drop.

Also, check this post out: [(d3.js)(.csv) Exclude column from Stacked Bar Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24575077/d3-js-csv-exclude-column-from-stacked-bar-graph)

```js
const data = [
 {
   name: 'John',
    x1: 1,
    x2: 1,
    x3: 0,
    total: 2
  },
  {
   name: 'July',
    x1: 0,
    x2: 1,
    x3: 1,
    total: 2
  }
]

const data2 = data.map( d => ({ name: d.name, x1: d.x1, x2: d.x2, x3: d.x3 }));
console.log(data2);

// you could also just do this
data.forEach( d => delete d.total);
console.log(data);
```